# Handling Optimistic Concurrency MVC Edit Form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, optimistic-concurrency

I'm having an issue with the edit form below, it never catches the *DbUpdateConcurrencyException*. What am I doing wrong?

**Class**

```
public class EditViewModel
{
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "PUT")]
public ActionResult EditData(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection formData) 
{

int year = Convert.ToInt32(formData["year"]);
int itemID = Convert.ToInt32(formData["itemID"]);
byte[] rowVersionID = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formData["RowVersion"]);
string row = Convert.ToBase64String(rowVersionID);    

if (ModelState.IsValid) {
string[] itemIDArray = formData.GetValues("item.itemID");

using(BusinessLogicLayer BLL = new BusinessLogicLayer()) {

   for (int i = 0; i < itemIDArray.Count(); i++) {
    try   
    {        
     BLL.UpdateItem(Convert.ToInt32(itemIDArray[i]));

     BLL.SaveChanges();

    } 

 catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex) //it never catches the exception

    {

     // Get the current entity values and the values in the database 
     // as instances of the entity type 
     var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
     var databaseValues = entry.GetDatabaseValues();

     ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to 
     edit has been modified by another user. Please try again!");      
    }
   }
  }
 }

 return View();
}
}
}
```

I also set the RowVersion column "Concurrency Mode" to fixed

[image]

**EDITS**

I also changed the catch block exception to a generic one and now I'm receiving the following error:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that `itemIDArray.Count()` is not zero?

Comment: Yes, it's not zero

Comment: It must be some other type then DbUpdateConcurrencyException, simply make the catch block of type Exception and if there is any exception it is guaranteed to enter the block and you can see the exact type of the exception

Comment: I changed the catch block to be of type "Exception" and now I'm getting an error in the following line: var entry = ex.Entries.Single(); it's saying that 'Exception' does not contain a definition for "Entries

Answer (score 0):

It probably is a different type of exception. Change the catch block to the generic Exception:

```
catch (Exception e){
    // your catch code
}
```

Then see what the kind of error it is throwing and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: I changed the catch block to a generic exception and now I'm getting an error in the following line: var entry = ex.Entries.Single(); it's saying that 'Exception' does not contain a definition for "Entries"